# How to retrieve a field from a dependent table from Users trough the class Auth:: in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have the follow relationship where `users` to `professionals` is one to many:

[image]

I would like to retrieve the `image_path` from professionals when a authorized user get access to the page.

This is what I have and it is working:

```
$id = \Auth::getUser()->id;
$image_path = Professional::where('user_id',$id)->pluck('image_path')->first();
```

I also did create a relation one to many in the model Users:

```
//Models/User
public function professionals(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Professional','user_id');
}
```

But I would like to retrieve inside blade something like this:

```
<img src='/storage/{{\Auth::getUser()->pluck('image_path')->first()}}' alt="Image Description">
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image_path' in 'field list' (SQL: select `image_path` from `users`)
```

How could I retrieve this field `image_path` from professionals using the `\Auth::`.

### Updatte

This code retrieves the correct information:

```
$user = User::find(5);
$user->professionals()->pluck('image_path')->first();

\Auth::user()->id  //5
```

This is what I have in the table professional
[image]

This one retrieves null: (Note: Auth::user() is user_id = 5 one row in professionals table)

```
\Auth::user()->professionals
\Auth::getUser()->professionals
```

And these returns `Call to undefined method App\User::professionals()`

```
\Auth::user()->professionals()
\Auth::getUser()->professionals()
```

Comment: You don't want to have a user with many professionals, by that i meant user cannat have many last_name and sex. Instead, you should do user as One Professionals  and Prefessionals belongsTo User

Comment: In this system not all users are a professional. And you are right, a user that is a professional cant have 2 resources in the table professional. I mean, the user will retrieve only 1 row when query this table by user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{{ Auth::user()->professionals()->pluck('image_path')->first() }}
```

or you can use your User model

```
{{ User::find(Auth::user()->id)->professionals()->pluck('image_path')->first() }}
```

It could be that Laravels default Auth, which is generated using php artisan make:auth is looking for the user model for relation in App\User.php, while you have your model in App\Models\User.php. Cannot confirm without `config\auth.php`.

**Update**

If you see the error `Call to undefined method App\User::professionals()`, it is looking for Model in `App\` Directory, while your model is in `App\Models\`,

I could solve the issue like this:

In `config/auth.php` that was my providers array:

```
'providers' => [
  'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\User::class,
  ],
...
],
```

And I have changed my model to  'model' => App\Models\User::class, This the new array:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
...
],
```

And now I can call `\Auth::user()->professionals->pluck('image_path')->first()` without errors because `professionals` is a method from `App\Models\User::class`.

Comment: That was my tough at the beginner. I have created an Update.

Comment: @zwitterion I tested by adding hasMany relation to User model, `Auth::user()->photos()->pluck('image')->first()`  this works

Comment: @zwitterion could it be that user is not logged in?

Comment: No I am the user logged in. I will update 2 more lines in order to show that (authorized user and relation)

Comment: I think the issue here is that my \Auth::user() OR \Auth::getUser() is not retrieving `->professionals`. Returns null, but I have a relation for the user I am logged (id=5).

Comment: by the way I am in Laravel 5.8. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: try `print_r(Auth::user()->professsionals()->first())`; it tried with `Auth::user()->photos()` gave me error, but not with `first()` or `get()`, tested on 5.8, `Auth::user()->photos` worked

Comment: I was usind dd() instead of print_r. But even print_r gives me `Call to undefined method App\User::professsionals()`  ... `print_r(\Auth::user()->professsionals()->first());`

Comment: are you using laravels default auth?  and `print_r()` and `dd()` are just choices, they perform the same function

Comment: This works 
        `$user = User::find(\Auth::user()->id);`
        `dd($user->professionals()->pluck('image_path')->first());`

Comment: @zwitterion then this too should work `User::find(Auth::user()->id)->professionals()->pluck('image_path')->first())`

Comment: @zwitterion I think why Auth::user() is not working because, by default laravels auth has its own user model in `App\User.php` while you have your user model in `App\Models\User.php`,

Comment: @zwitterion i was able to reproduce your error with some changes to `config\auth.php`, can you check your `'providers'` in auth.php?

Comment: Now I understand the issue and I can finnaly retrieve the data properly. You are right. The User::class that is used to the Authorization is defined in providers config/auth.php. Mine was `'model' => App\User::class,` and as you said this have no `hasMany` method. I just comented out this one and switched to `'model' => App\Models\User::class`. Now I am able to use `\Auth::user()->professionals->pluck('image_path')->first()` inside blade. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img src='/storage/{{Auth::user()->professionals->first()->image_path}}' alt="Image Description">
```

Comment: Hi Fabian \Auth::user()->professionals is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call it this way and let me if it works

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/'.Auth::user()->professionals->image_path}}" alt="Image Description">
```

UPDATED CODE

```
  @if(Auth::user()->professionals >='1')
       <img src="{{asset('storage/'.Auth::user()->professionals->image_path}}" alt="Image Description">
   @else
       //Show something different
   @endif
```

Also you can use isNotEmpty() or @Empty()

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: It is because the user doesn't have record in table professional. You will have to use something like IF statement. SEE Updated code

Comment: Yes it is. I have created an Update. It retrieves correctly when using $user = User::find(5); with is the user with record in the table professionals.

Comment: So use the the IF statement in case you have a user without record in professionals table just to prevent the error to.. And a thumbs up to the answer will be very helpful. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that users can have many professionals. If you can eager load the professional you need for that given user in your controller it would be better. If you need access to all of the users professionals on the blade then you can constrain inside of the blade like so:

```
{{ \Auth::getUser()->professionals->where('user_id',$id)->first()->image_path ?? '' }}
```

I threw in the `?? ''` so if no professional was found it would just spit out the empty string.

Comment: I put some update. \Auth::getUser()->professionals is returning null.